# Python prints new line

Tags: json, python-3.x

Can some one explain why this char on line 17 in the script below is printed on a new line?

```
from pathlib import Path

pathList = Path("states").glob("**/*.*")
OUT = open("resources/states.json", "w")

OUT.write("{\n")
for path in pathList:
    F = open(str(path),"r")
    L = F.readlines()
    OUT.write("\"" + str(path) + "\":\n")
    OUT.write("[\n")
    for l in L:
        s = l.split("=")
        print(s)
        OUT.write("{")
        OUT.write(" \"name\": " + "\"" + s[0] + "\"" + ",\n")
        OUT.write(" \"code\": " + "\"" + (s[0] if len(s) == 1 else s[1]) + "\"")
        OUT.write("}" + ("" if l == L[-1] else ",") +  "\n")
    OUT.write("],\n\n")
    F.close()
OUT.write("}\n")
OUT.flush()
OUT.close()
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
    "states/APO_states.txt": [
        {
            "name": "Armed Forces Americas",
            "code": "AA
"
        },
        {
            "name": "Armed Forces",
            "code": "AE
"
        },

    ...
```

What is wrong? I have tried to flush it, but it does not help.

Comment: Can you explain why are you not using a module designed for this purpose - [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)?

Comment: `print` automatically terminates with a newline. If you want to avoid that, use `print(... , end='')`

Comment: Sorry, but I'm using write, not print. The last char "\"" should be included in the line before ending it, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `L = F.readlines()` looks like `['key1=value1\n', ...` (note the `\n`, it doesn't disappear; `\r\n` is also possible instead), so `s = l.split("=")` is like `['key1', 'value1\n']`. A solution:  `s = l.strip().split("=")`.

Comment: Yes, thats it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, you want to write [**JSON**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). Instead of writing an encoder and decoder yourself you better use the module, since it guarantees that the output is valid.

We thus have to construct a program that constructs a dictionary `data` with `sublist`s that each contain a `dict`ionary with `'name'` and `'code'` keys. When that is done, we can write the corresponding JSON to the `OUT` file handler.

```
from pathlib import Path
import json

pathList = Path("states").glob("**/*.*")
with open("resources/states.json", "w") as OUT:
    data = {}
    for path in pathList:
        with open(str(path),"r") as F:
            sublist = []
            for l in F:
                s = l.strip().split("=")
                print(s)
                sublist.append({'name':s[0],'code':s[0] if len(s) == 0 else s[1]})
        data[str(path)] = sublist
    json.dump(data,OUT)
```

You also better use `with` statements, since these will automatically flush and close the file once you leave the with scope.

Comment: Thanks, that is a solution. But still confused of why it didn't work.